# VirtualBox access services from guest on host over WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bridge

I've read that the network bridge in VirtualBox over WiFi works slowly. For me it doesn't work at all because the request in the browser takes too long and times out.

Is there any way else than network bridge to access the services of the guest machine on the host over WiFi?

Edit: 
[image: Network settings]

Comment: Your question probably needs clarification. The host's network device isn't relevant for the guest. If it work on the host then the problem is at the VM settings but it doesn't matter if it's WiFi, Ethernet, tethered or other. It matters if you're using that device *directly* connected to the VM (USB passtrought) but that isn't a bridge or anything of the sort.

Comment: I meant that the guest is using the WiFi. I use WiFi in the network adapter settings of my guest system because I've got told to do so because of security. I didn't question that because I don't know too much about having an active VM in an internal network.

Comment: Please [edit] and include the virtualbox settings. Regarding security I don't know much but I can't imagine how can a "bridged adapter > WiFi" is safer than, say, NAT.

Comment: It's because the WiFi isn't connected to the internal network. It's supposed to be used by guests.

Comment: OK. And back to the beginning, is the WiFi connected in  the host?

Comment: Yes it is connected to the guest WiFi and also to the internal network over ethernet.

Comment: Then I suggest testing the connection at the host with the WiFi only. If it works fine there but still doesn't in the VM, that needs troubleshooting that's "above my paycheck" but someone else may give some hints.

Comment: Hm that's weird. I  did as you supposed and unplugged the ethernet cable. I couldn't call the service from my browser. But after plugging it in again it worked as I wanted with the network bridge over WiFi. Thank you very much for your help.